# How should I add JavaScript to a child theme?

Tags: javascript, child-theme

Say I wanted to add a site-wide snippet of JavaScript to my website but was using a child theme so as to not tamper with the original theme. Would I have to add a new .js file to the child theme, or could the script go into functions.php? Or, even better, could it be added with a plugin?

Answer (score 4):

You can do different things:

1. **Enqueue** the new JS file via `plugin`
2. **Enqueue** the new JS file via `functions.php`
3. Add your JS code into `functions.php` through `wp_header` or `wp_footer`

For adding new JS files to a wordpress site you should **enqueue** these files with  `wp_enqueue_style()` and/or `wp_enqueue_script()`.

This is the proper and safest way.

I would go the route and create a simple, small plugin for that, because this is theme independent.

You *could* also use an hook to `wp_header` or `wp_footer`. Inside this hook you can write your JS code.

But the proper way is enqueueing these files which will work something like this:

```
function prfx_frontend_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-css', plugins_url('/assets/css/plugin.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-plugin-js', plugins_url('/assets/js/jquery.my-script-min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prfx_frontend_enqueue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Add the javascript file to the folder and call [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) with the proper filename. You can do this either in the child theme or a plugin, it really does not matter (from a technical perspective).

If you aren't adding more functionality, I would not create a custom plugin for this and just include it within the child theme's function.php.

Comment: If I go the route of creating a new .js file, does it need a particular name, or could I just name it something relevant to its purpose?

Comment: You can use any name you like - something relevant to its purpose is usually preferred. Then with calling `wp_enqueue_script` you provide that given name